# Good web-service based API for getting the latest CME Globex future data

Tags: data-request, api

We are looking for a good url/json/python based API for getting the latest CME Globex future quotes. We want to run it on command line based Linux server, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Quandl has daily [CME futures data](https://www.quandl.com/data/CME-Chicago-Mercantile-Exchange-Futures-Data) publicly available for free, updated daily with what looks to be a 1 day lag or less (at ~4am Eastern there is data from the previous day).

It may not be Globex-specific but instead an aggregation of CME's different [market access platforms](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/market-tech-and-data-services.html), I'm not sure.

Comment: Ehm... However, we would need the life CME future data though...... But thank you for suggesting.